# Network device failing to access groups from Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, authentication, groups, tacacs+

Occurs only for only 1 user , when TACACS+ tries to authenticate and retreive groups it fails, according to logs authentication is a success but fails when retreiving groups with error, "24027  Groups search ended with an error".

-> User id works well with all other applications except TACACS+.
->Might be a Cisco issue but is there a chance Domain Controller is resetting the connections?

Please let me know if any questions to confirm anything.

Comment: Is this one user a member of a large number of groups, or cross-domain groups?

Comment: compared to others whose access is working group count is less; not sure about cross-domain groups.